# Ошибка mySQL #1064

Tags: mysql

Структура таблицы: `style`, `url`, `left`

При `SELECT * FROM style WHERE style!="8-bit" ORDER BY style` выборка идет нормально,

но вот при `SELECT * FROM style WHERE left!="false" ORDER BY style` получаю

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '!="false" ORDER BY style' at line 1
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

left  резервированное слово, напишите style.left например

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `style` WHERE `left` != 'false'
```

Comment: я лично не люблю эти обратные кавычки в mysql ибо они частенько в шелле раскрываются до system()